# Find squares for $m^2+n$ and $n^2+m$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Are there any natural $m$ and $n$, that $m^2+n$ and $n^2+m$ are squares?

Proof:
I tried to mod them

Comment: If you consider zero a natural number, then sure.

Comment: Also, I wouldn't be surprised if there were no other solution due to the form of the quadratic function. If you fix an $m$, $n>m$. When we try to square $n$, $m$ would need to be larger than $n$, but it contradicts our first assumption. Don't trust me on this one too hard.

Comment: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1046718__4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose , $m$ and $n$ are non-negative integers.

Using Goddard's idea :

If we assume $0<n\le m$, then we have $$m^2<m^2+n<m^2+2m+1=(m+1)^2$$, so $m^2+n$ is not a square.

If we assume $0<m\le n$, then we have $$n^2<n^2+m<n^2+2n+1=(n+1)^2$$, so $n^2+m$ is not a square.

So, $m^2+n$ and $n^2+m$ can only be both squares, if $m=0$ or $n=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with $m^2+n$, in order for that to be a square, fix $m$ to be any natural number. The next possible square is formed by adding at least $n>m$.

Then, when we try to satisfy the second equation, $n^2+m$, the same situation applies, but the condition can't be met for $m>n$. Therefore the pair can't exist.

I'd appreciate if someone checked my proof to not give OP false hopes.

Comment: Yep.  WLOG $m\geq n$.  Then $m^2 < m^2+n < m^2 +2m+1 = (m+1)^2.$